# What is the difference between () and [] when using dynamic allocation?

Tags: c++

I thought that bracket '[]' and '()' is identical when performing dynamic allocation in cpp, but this code prints error. Originally, 5-size array shoulde include index 0 to 4 isn't it? Is there any problem in my code? I searched for it in cppreference.com, and cannot find it.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void){
    int* p1 = new int[5];
    int* p2 = new int(5);
    p1[4] = 1;
    cout << p1[4]; // no error
    p2[4] = 1;
    cout << p2[4]; // error
}
```

Comment: `cout << p2[4]; // error` is undefined behavior but may work and give you a false sense that the code is correct.

Comment: What would make dynamic allocation the special thing where `[]` and `()` are the same, when they are not the same anywhere else in the language?

Answer (score 5):

`new int[5]` constructs an `int` array with 5 elements, while `new int(5)` constructs a single `int` with value 5.

ref: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new

Comment: I would add: if you are a beginner (or an expert), you should generally be using std::vector for dynamic-sized arrays and unique_ptr for heap-allocated values. Then you’d have `auto v = std::vector<int>(5); auto ptr = std::make_unique<int>(5);` also wouldn’t leak. (Your program leaks.)

Comment: @Ben `auto v = std::vector<int>(5);` would be better as `std::vector<int> v(5);` instead. Also, `std::unique_ptr` *can* be used for arrays, eg: `auto arr = std::make_unique<int[]>(5);`

Comment: The first one is a matter of style. Personally I prefer the consistency of `auto name = ...;` but I'd go either way. And yes, `std::make_unique<int[]>(5);` would work too, but I think people should consider `std::vector` as the go-to heap-allocated array type.